# No Snmp Data Collection For HPE G7 In Zabbix

Tags: database, server, snmp, zabbix, zabbix-api

I have a HPE G7 and Zabbix v6, So I want to monitor this server on zabbix I fill the snmp data on iLO, but I get No Snmp Data Collection on Zabbix!

I try to fill snmp data on iLO!It happens on HPE-G7!
Do you have any way to solve this problem!?

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible causes for this issue:

- ILO SNMP settings: double-check that the SNMP settings on your ILO are configured correctly and match the settings in Zabbix.
- Firewall issues: Ensure that any firewall between Zabbix and ILO allows traffic on SNMP port (UDP/161 by default).
- Incorrect SNMP version: make sure that the SNMP version you are using in Zabbix is compatible with SNMPv2c.
- Timeout issues: If the SNMP data collection takes too long, the request may time out.
- Verify if the SNMP service is running on the HPE G7 server, if not start it.

To test SNMP connectivity from the Zabbix server to the HPE G7 server, you can use the nmap and snmpwalk commands.

```
nmap -sU -p 161 <HPE G7 server's IP address>
```

The SNMP port should be `open`, not `open|filtered`, in the nmap output.

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c <community string> <HPE G7 server's IP address> | head
```

If working, the snmpwalk command will show a bunch of SNMP metrics. When not working, it usually shows a timeout error.